# Definition of Critical Point at endpoints

Tags: calculus, definition

On a math test, we were instructed to find critical points of the function $f(x) = x\sqrt{30-x^2}$. I calculated where the derivative was 0, at $\pm \sqrt{15}$, and I knew the domain was restricted to $(-\sqrt{30}, \sqrt{30})$.

I also was aware that the derivative was undefined at those points, but neither of those points was infinity, in a sense. Like, neither of the "endpoints" was an asymptote, $f(\pm \sqrt{30}) = 0$.

I got this problem wrong because I included neither $\sqrt{30}$ nor $-\sqrt{30}$ in the list of critical points.

What is the concrete definition of critical point?

Comment: Was the domain restricted to $[-\sqrt{30},\sqrt{30}]$ or $(-\sqrt{30},\sqrt{30})$ ?

Comment: [ ] @LanierFreeman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the concrete definition of critical point?

Before giving the concrete definition, it's better to have a rough idea about critical points.

> *Critical points* are points at which an extremum could **possibly** occur.

*Source: [© CalculusQuest™](https://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth251/cq/Stage7/Lesson/critical.html)*

[image: different types of critical points] endpoint: [image: endpoint extremum]

*Image sources: [Solomon Xie's story](https://medium.com/self-study-calculus/critical-points-bed69759e06b), http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/MinMaxValues_Files/image002.png*

Therefore, it makes sense to includes three types of points in the domain

1. points at which the derivative of $f$ *vanishes* (local min/max, points of inflection)
2. *endpoints* of domain
3. points at which the derivative of $f$ is *undefined* (corner, cusp, points of discontinuity)

> On a math test, we were instructed to find critical points of the function $f(x) = x\sqrt{30-x^2}$.

The given domain of $f$ is *not* clearly stated in the question.  The open interval $(-\sqrt{30},\sqrt{30})$ is just OP's *perception*.  Taking account of OP's comment and of the 3rd paragraph of the question body, it *seems* that OP has *mistaken the domain of* $f$, which should actually be the *closed and bounded interval* $[-\sqrt{30},\sqrt{30}]$.

Find the critical points type by type.

1. $f'(x) = \sqrt{30 - x^2} - x \, \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{30 - x^2}} = \dfrac{30 - 2x^2}{\sqrt{30 - x^2}}$, so $f'(x) = 0$ iff $x = \pm\sqrt{15}$
2. endpoints of the domain of $f$: $x = \pm\sqrt{30}$
3. The denominator of $f'(x)$ vanishes iff $x^2 = 30$, i..e the endpoints of the domain of $f$.

Conclusion: The critical points of $f$ are $x = \pm\sqrt{15}, \pm\sqrt{30}$.

## Alternative solution 1

Observe that $f$ is an odd function, since it's a product of an odd function $x \mapsto x$ and an even function $x \mapsto \sqrt{30 - x^2}$.  Therefore, it suffices to find the global maximum of $f$.  Since $f$ vanishes at the endpoints and the midpoint of the domain, the global extrema are actualy local extrema.  The fact that $f$ is odd allows us to concentrates on nonnegative real numbers and apply [a.m.-g.m.-inequality](/questions/tagged/a.m.-g.m.-inequality)
$$\frac{a^2 + b^2}{2} \ge ab$$ with $a = x$ and $b = \sqrt{30 - x^2}$.
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2 + (30 - x^2)}{2} \ge& x \sqrt{30 - x^2} \\
x \sqrt{30 - x^2} \le& 15
\end{align}
Equality holds iff $a = b$.
\begin{align}
\text{i.e. } \quad x &= \sqrt{30 - x^2} \\
x^2 &= 30 - x^2 \\
x &= \pm\sqrt{15}
\end{align}
This elementary solution in [algebra-precalculus](/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) is useful in [contest-math](/questions/tagged/contest-math) since you *don't* need to use [calculus](/questions/tagged/calculus).

## Alternative solution 2

It's *even simpler* to make use of [quadratics](/questions/tagged/quadratics).  Note that in the right half of the domain, everything is *nonnegative*, so squaring $f$ *won't* affect the answer.  As a result, consider $$(f(x))^2 = x^2 (30 - x^2) = -(x^2 - 15)^2 + 15^2 \le 15^2.$$  This gives the *same* maximizer $x = \sqrt{15}$ as expected.